# How to set fit height and width for tcbox according to the text inside?

Tags: formatting, width, tcolorbox, height

I want to place a word into a `\tcbox`, but the box has too much space around the word. For example, the word "EQUAL".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have several options here: you can use the `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` keys (and perhaps also `boxsep`) to control the space between text and frame on each of the sides or you could use the `size` key to get some predefined sizes (the accepted values `minimal`, `tight`, `fbox`, `small`, `title`, and `normal` and their effect are illustrated in my example code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\tcbox{EQUAL}

\tcbox[top=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,bottom=0pt]{EQUAL}

\foreach \s in {minimal,tight,fbox,small,title,normal} 
{
\tcbox[size=\s,on line]{EQUAL} 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If looked carefully, the top padding of is quite smaller than the bottom padding. To fix this for `title` size, use `\tcbox[size=title,on line,top=3pt]{EQUAL}`

Answer (score 5):

If it is only one word inside the box, you may use `tikz` straight away. Change `inner sep` values as you wish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\tikz[baseline={(a.base)}]\node[draw=blue,rounded corners=0.5ex,fill=red!40!white,inner sep=1pt](a){#1};}
\begin{document}
  \mybox{hello} my world \mybox{EQUAL}
\end{document}
```

[image]