# How to restrict width of tcolorbox according to the length of the text it contains

Tags: formatting, pdftex, width, tcolorbox

I have created a `tcolorbox` (as given in `tcolorbox` version 3.40 manual - page 155)

LaTeX Code:

```
\tcbset{
        enhanced,
        colback=red!5!white,
        boxrule=0.1pt,
        colframe=red!75!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries
       }
       My own shadow
       \begin{tcolorbox}[title=My own shadow,
       lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}%
       {black!50!white}]
       This is a tcolorbox.
       \end{tcolorbox}
```

Current Output:
[image]

Expected Output (produced by explicitly setting: width=\linewidth/3):

[image]

My problem is:

This box contains only a little text, but occupies the whole textwidth

I have referred a related question here:
[How to set fit height and width for tcbox according to the text inside?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191131/how-to-set-fit-height-and-width-for-tcbox-according-to-the-text-inside)

but the options like: `minimal`,`tight` distort the box.

**Is there any option through which this box can grow automatically in width depending on the width of the text contained in it?**

Note: Adding \hbox solves this problem for normal text, but leads to a compilation error in case of bullet list.

Example:

```
\tcbset
    {
        enhanced,
        left=8mm,
        right=8mm,
        boxrule=0.4pt,
        colback=red!5!white,
        boxrule=0.1pt,
        colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    }
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
                        title=\begin{center}Sample Title\end{center},
                        hbox,
                        lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}{black!50!white}
                     ]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First Line
    \item Second Line
    \end{itemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}
```

Compilation Error: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Just for reference -- The updated answer shows how to resolve this issue as well (using varwidth)

Comment: Hello, to center the title you can use `title=Sample Title,halign title=center`, instead of `title=\begin{center}Sample Title\end{center}`. Happy holidays, cheers!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `hbox`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}


\tcbset{
        enhanced,
        colback=red!5!white,
        boxrule=0.1pt,
        colframe=red!75!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries
       }
       My own shadow
       \begin{tcolorbox}[title=My own shadow,hbox,    %%<<---- here
       lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}%
       {black!50!white}]
       This is a tcolor box
       \end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

For revised question, you may need `varwidth` package to insert the `itemize`. Also to center the title, use the option `center title` instead of `\begin{center}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}   %% provides varwidth environment

\begin{document}


\tcbset{
        enhanced,
        colback=red!5!white,
        boxrule=0.1pt,
        colframe=red!75!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries
       }
       My own shadow
       \begin{tcolorbox}[title=My own shadow,center title,hbox,    %%<<---- here
       lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}%
       {black!50!white}]
       \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
       This is a tcolor box.
       \begin{itemize}
         \item First Line
         \item Second Line
       \end{itemize}
       \end{varwidth}
       \end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that hbox doesn't work in case of bullets inside tcolorbox. Can you please give some hint on this?

Comment: @SandeepSingh Are you using an `itemize` inside? Can you post the content in your question instead of `This is a tcolorbox` line?

Comment: I was trying to generalize the usage for this box, added the code for bullet list. Thanks

Comment: @SandeepSingh No not like that. See the edited answer. Also use `center title`.

Comment: Apparently `hbox` is throwing a `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>` error (which goes away I remove `hbox`)

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps there is `natural width` option, I did not find it.

A small workaround: Wrap the text into a box and get the width of it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{This is a tcolorbox}


\tcbset{
        enhanced,
        colback=red!5!white,
        boxrule=0.1pt,
        colframe=red!75!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries
       }
       My own shadow
       \begin{tcolorbox}[title=My own shadow,
       lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}%
       {black!50!white},text width=\wd\mybox]
       \usebox{\mybox}  % Release it ;-)
       \end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

Since the width of text is relevant, one should use the (new) `text width` option, not the full `width` option.

[image]

Comment: How could this be put into the beamerTheme.sty file? Where would you include the tcolorbox configuration?

Comment: @Vass: This should work basically out of the box for `beamer` theme file as well or use a `\newtcolorbox` command in order to incorporate the options given to `\tcbset`.

Comment: I tried to and found new difficulties. Maybe you want to provide an answer to my question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/391241/1026 ?

Comment: @Vass: That's a beamer related question. There are real experts for `beamer`, but I am not one of them