Changing rows in the same tcbox
I am using the tcolorbox, tcbox;
and I would like to have the \\ or \newline (ability of changing rows) within the tccheckbox that I defined below. But I could not make it successfully.
Any way to fix it?
 \documentclass[aps]{revtex4}

 
\usepackage{amsmath}
 

\usepackage{tcolorbox}


    \newcommand\tccheckbox[2][on line]{%
      \sbox0{\tcbox[#1]{#2}}%
      \rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dimexpr\dp0+\ht0}%
      \tabto*{\linewidth}%
      \ifdim\dimexpr\linewidth-\TabPrevPos > \wd0\relax
        \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
      \else
        \tabto{0pt}%
      \fi    
      \copy0%
      \rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dimexpr\dp0+\ht0}%
      \allowbreak
    }
    
    
    
\begin{document}

\tccheckbox[]{
123 \\
ABC
}

\tccheckbox[]{
123 \newline
ABC
}

\tccheckbox[]{
$\frac{123}{ABC}$
}

\tccheckbox[]{
$\substack{{123}\\{ABC}}$
}

\end{document}

I am using the $\frac{}{}$ and $\substack{{}\\{}}$ to demonstrate the effect I wanted for \\ and \newline.
Failed demo:


maybe useful https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191133/41144

You could use a tcbox with the varwidth upper option:
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newtcbox{\tccheckbox}[1][]{on line,varwidth upper,baseline}    
            
\begin{document}

\tccheckbox[]{
123 \\
ABC
}

\tccheckbox[]{
123 \newline
ABC
}

\tccheckbox[]{
$\frac{123}{ABC}$
}

\tccheckbox[]{
$\substack{{123}\\{ABC}}$
}

\end{document}


